# How do I create an if-then formula in excel that produces a written text answer?

Tags: excel, if-statement, text

=IF(J35>130,["Way_Above_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=119,J35<=130),["Above_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=109,J35<=118),["High_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=89,J35<=108),["Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=80,J35<=90),["Low_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=68,J35<=79),["Below_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=61,J35<=67),["Way_Below_Average"]))

I am trying to create a "report template" that takes the raw testing data of students from a Normed test...and creates a description of the score as compared to peers in the same grade.

=IF(J35>130,["Way_Above_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=119,J35<=130),["Above_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=109,J35<=118),["High_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=89,J35<=108),["Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=80,J35<=90),["Low_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=68,J35<=79),["Below_Average"]),IF(AND(J35>=61,J35<=67),["Way_Below_Average"]))

I keep getting error messages about syntax and name...want this to create a text descriptor from the raw standard score.

Comment: You're really just describing a VLookup. Instead of having this enormous mess of formulas, just define the ranges you'd like in a range of cells in ascending order, put the descriptions to the right of them, then do the VLookup on your values. It's much easier to maintain, and plus, since the values don't need to be hardcoded, you could define them based on the actual numbers involved (25th percentile, 50th percentile, etc)

Comment: Your code has mistakes in it. Remove all square brackets, and just leave the double quotes. Also, remove the closing round bracket after your square brackets. There was nothing opening that round bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Just taking the first two levels, I would put:

```
=IF(J35>130,"Way_Above_Average",IF(J35>=119,"Above_Average"),"")
```

As you should not need the square brackets or the and() as if the number tested is above 130 it has already been controlled.

Just for fun, here is a vlookup equivalent:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(J35,{61,68,80,89,109,119,130}),"Way_Below_","Below_","Low_","","High_","Above_","Way_Above_") & "Average","Below_61")
```